# No output for OCRmyPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ocr, google-colaboratory

I'm using OCRmyPDF to extract text form scanned pdf files. I use codes from [this Colab notebook](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fgist%2Fdanshorstein%2Fa6f1039d73a1f9bf150f3f71e2c33801%2F023-converting-scanned-pdfs-to-excel-for-accounting.ipynb%3Fauthuser%3D1&v=glJi3LBgn9U&event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa0l4bDhTczFrdFVUTzhoUXpGS1NSWjdlcERuZ3xBQ3Jtc0tucGh1V1lGNjJaMDUzZ1RVZXRPdmRFYzhPU3JyS3N3X3J5YS1JaGlHVUlGamwwd25rTmRSUWZRVVpycTgwUEN0c09lT3ZTUW1tSjR1NjdqeW8xMG41YjZ0SHpvNE1fMVZ6cS04enFrMGpjb3hTSVhBRQ%3D%3D) for that purpose. The only difference is that instead of downloading the pdf file from an online url, I use the pdf file stored on my local machine (replaced it {file_name} instead of {invoice_pdf}). Everything looks fine up to the point I run:

```
os.system(f'ocrmypdf {file_name} output.pdf')
```

Instead of 0, I get 512! and the next line, when I run `!ocrmypdf Performance Evaluations.pdf output.pdf`   , I get an unrecognized error message which reads like:

```
usage: ocrmypdf [-h] [-l LANGUAGE] [--image-dpi DPI]
                [--output-type {pdfa,pdf,pdfa-1,pdfa-2}] [--sidecar [FILE]]
                [--version] [-j N] [-q] [-v [VERBOSE]] [--title TITLE]
                [--author AUTHOR] [--subject SUBJECT] [--keywords KEYWORDS]
                [-r] [--remove-background] [-d] [-c] [-i] [--oversample DPI]
                [-f] [-s] [--skip-big MPixels] [--max-image-mpixels MPixels]
                [--tesseract-config CFG] [--tesseract-pagesegmode PSM]
                [--tesseract-oem MODE]
                [--pdf-renderer {auto,tesseract,hocr,sandwich}]
                [--tesseract-timeout SECONDS]
                [--rotate-pages-threshold CONFIDENCE]
                [--pdfa-image-compression {auto,jpeg,lossless}]
                [--user-words FILE] [--user-patterns FILE] [--skip-repair]
                [-k] [-g] [--flowchart FLOWCHART]
                input_pdf_or_image output_pdf
ocrmypdf: error: unrecognized arguments: output.pdf
```

Finally, running the following line:

```
with pdfplumber.open('output.pdf') as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text(x_tolerance=2)
    print(text)
```

returns

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8274f7005856> in <module>()
----> 1 with pdfplumber.open('output.pdf') as pdf:
      2     page = pdf.pages[0]
      3     text = page.extract_text(x_tolerance=2)
      4     print(text)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pdfplumber/pdf.py in open(cls, path_or_fp, **kwargs)
     56     def open(cls, path_or_fp, **kwargs):
     57         if isinstance(path_or_fp, (str, pathlib.Path)):
---> 58             fp = open(path_or_fp, "rb")
     59             inst = cls(fp, **kwargs)
     60             inst.close = fp.close

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.pdf'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file name contains spaces, then you need to enclose the name in quotation marks.

```
ocrmypdf "Performance Evaluations.pdf" output.pdf
```

or

```
ocrmypdf 'Performance Evaluations.pdf' output.pdf
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. The reason I created a variable for file_name in is that I'll be using this ocrmypdf over and over to convert a couple of hundreds of scanned PDFs into text without changing the file name every time I run it. But as you noted, every time I use the variable instead of the actual file's name I run into the error. Can you suggest any solution to bypass this problem?

Comment: test this:

 os.system( f'ocrmypdf \'{file_name}\' output.pdf')

Comment: That worked and now I get 0 for that line, but the next line (!ocrmypdf {file_name} output.pdf )  still sends the same error  (ocrmypdf: error: unrecognized arguments: output.pdf)

Comment: Double quotes? os.system (f'ocrmypdf \ "{file_name} \" output.pdf ')

Comment: Thanks. Double quotes didn't work. I'm using single quotes to do the job.